# Adjust code to choose a specific column depending on the difference between dates

Tags: r

The code below works perfectly, I'd just like to make an adjustment. Note that I only get a specific line from `SPV`. In this example above it matches `date2="2021-07-09"` and `Code = CDE`. So far OK. However, I would like to select only 1 number, which uses the following condition `ymd(dmda) - ymd(min(df1$date1))`. That is, if I do this code thath I mentioned I get a difference of 11 days, so the value I want is the eleventh column counting from `DR00_DR00_PV`, that is, in this case the correct column is: `DR010_DR010_PV`. So the value for this case is `5`. How to adjust this?

```
> SPV
       date1      date2 Code   Week DR00_DR00_PV DR01_DR01_PV DR02_DR02_PV DR03_DR03_PV DR04_DR04_PV DR05_DR05_PV DR06_DR06_PV
1 2021-06-28 2021-07-09  CDE Friday            5            5            5            5            5            5            5
  DR07_DR07_PV DR08_DR08_PV DR09_DR09_PV DR010_DR010_PV DR011_DR011_PV DR012_DR012_PV DR013_DR013_PV
1            5            5            5              5              5              5              5
```

Executable code

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

df1 <- structure(
  list(date1= c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-06-25","2021-06-25","2021-06-27","2021-07-07","2021-07-07","2021-07-09","2021-07-09","2021-07-09"),
       Code = c("FDE","ABC","ABC","ABC","CDE","FGE","ABC","CDE"),
       Week= c("Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Wednesday","Wednesday","Friday","Friday","Friday"),
       DR1 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,5),
       DR00 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6), DR01= c(4,2,6,7,3,2,7,4),DR02= c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5),
       DR03 = c(5,4,3,3,6,2,1,9),DR04 = c(5,4,5,3,6,2,1,9),
       DR05 = c(2,4,3,3,5,6,7,8),DR06 = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8),
       DR07 = c(0,0,0,1,2,0,0,0),DR08 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),DR09 = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),DR010 = c(4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 
       DR011 = c(0,0,0,3,0,0,0,5),DR012 = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0),DR013 = c(0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

selection = startsWith(names(df1), "DRM")

df1[selection][is.na(df1[selection])] = 0

dt1 <- as.data.table(df1)

cols <- grep("^DR0", colnames(dt1), value = TRUE)

medi_ana <- 
  dt1[, (paste0(cols, "_PV")) := DR1 - .SD, .SDcols = cols
  ][, lapply(.SD, median), by = .(Code, Week), .SDcols = paste0(cols, "_PV") ]


SPV<-df1%>%
  inner_join(medi_ana, by = c('Code', 'Week')) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("^DR0\\d+$"), ~.x + 
                  get(paste0(cur_column(), '_PV')),
                .names = '{col}_{col}_PV')) %>%
  select(date1:Week, DR00_DR00_PV:last_col())%>%
  data.frame()

dmda<-"2021-07-09"
CodeChosse<-"CDE"

SPV<-SPV %>%
  filter(date2 == dmda, Code == CodeChosse)

> SPV
       date1      date2 Code   Week DR00_DR00_PV DR01_DR01_PV DR02_DR02_PV DR03_DR03_PV DR04_DR04_PV DR05_DR05_PV DR06_DR06_PV
1 2021-06-28 2021-07-09  CDE Friday            5            5            5            5            5            5            5
  DR07_DR07_PV DR08_DR08_PV DR09_DR09_PV DR010_DR010_PV DR011_DR011_PV DR012_DR012_PV DR013_DR013_PV
1            5            5            5              5              5              5              5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you just need to add a `select` statement to your final `dplyr` pipeline, like this:

```
SPV %>%
  filter(date2 == dmda, Code == CodeChosse) %>% 
  select(date1:Week, as.numeric(ymd(dmda)-ymd(min(df1$date1)))+4)
```

Output:

```
       date1      date2 Code   Week DR010_DR010_PV
1 2021-06-28 2021-07-09  CDE Friday              5
```

Explanation: The `select` statement here is taking a combination of slice of columns (i.e `date1:Week`) and a numeric index of a column (i.e. 11+4).  Why 4? Because the index of the column of interest is 4 more than 11 (i.e. columns `date1` thru `Week` are columns 1 thru 4.

If you only want the number 5, you could do this:

```
SPV %>%
  filter(date2 == dmda, Code == CodeChosse) %>% 
  pull(as.numeric(ymd(dmda)-ymd(min(df1$date1)))+4)
```

Output:

```
[1] 5
```

Comment: Thanks @langtang for the reply, but I would like just the number, that is, `5`. In addtiional, why `+ 4` in the code?

Comment: Sorry, see my edit and explanation